# How to call a web service on system startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm having self hosted web server on that server i have a web service.

I need to call that service from another system on system start-up (client system start-up).

For that i created a windows application and set this application on system start-up on client system.

It works fine.

But can any one tell me is there any other way to call this service from another system.

Comment: [Window Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be the solution of your question.

Comment: Calling windows application from other system?

Comment: Problem solved by windows service.Thanks Shekhar